# Solving $y' + \frac{1}{2}xy + y^{2} = 0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the ODE $$y' + \frac{1}{2}xy + y^{2} = 0.$$ Mathematica gives that the answer is $$y(x) = \frac{e^{-x^2/4}}{C + 2\int_{0}^{x/2}e^{-t^{2}}\, dt}.$$ Of course, if I take this answer and plug it into the ODE, I am able to get the answer, but how does one derive this solution from the ODE?

If I multiply the ODE by $e^{x^{2}/4}$, then $$(e^{x^{2}/4}y)' = -e^{x^{2}/4}y^{2}$$ but then this gives $$e^{x^{2}/4}y = -\int_{0}^{x}e^{s^{2}/4}y(s)^{2}\, ds.$$ How does one get from here to the solution Mathematica gave me?

Comment: Try $y(x)=1/z(x)$.

Comment: I just wanted to add, as you've already solved the problem, that these types of ODE are called Bernoulli Differential Equations, if you wanted to google and learn about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is an integrating factor.  If you multiply the whole equation by $e^{-x^2/4}$ observe that you can make the simplification

$$
e^{-x^2/4}y' + \frac{1}{2}xe^{-x^2/4} y + e^{-x^2/4}y^2 \;\; \Longrightarrow\;\; e^{-x^2/4}\frac{y'}{y^2} + \frac{1}{2}x e^{-x^2/4} \frac{1}{y} + e^{-x^2/4} \;\; =\;\; 0.
$$

Observe now that we can simplify this expression by rewriting it as

\begin{eqnarray*}
-e^{-x^2/4}\frac{y'}{y^2} - \frac{1}{2} xe^{-x^2/4} \frac{1}{y} & = & e^{-x^2/4} \\
\frac{d}{dx} \left ( \frac{e^{-x^2/4}}{y} \right ) & = & e^{-x^2/4}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Integrating both sides we obtain

$$
\frac{e^{-x^2/4}}{y} \;\; =\;\; \int_0^{x/2} e^{-t^2} dt + C
$$

and therefore

$$
y(x) \;\; =\;\; \frac{e^{-x^2/4}}{C + \int_0^{x/2} e^{-t^2}dt}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

From the result you obtained, it is quite clear that there is a first change of variable $y=\frac 1z$ which, after simplification gives $$2z'-x z-2=0$$ Integrating $2z'-xz=0$ gives $$z=C e^{\frac{x^2}{4}}$$ and then $$C'=e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}$$ that is to say $$C=\sqrt{\pi }\, \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+K$$ and then the result.